# SSRS with XML SharePoint Dataset Parameter with multiple values error

Tags: xml, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sharepoint-list

I'm trying to add `Allow Multi Values` option to existing working report and getting this error **Multiple selection not valid ..Because it's not supported by the data extension**.

- Data source = Microsoft SharePoint List

I first time work with the report where Dataset is actual XML schema, so I see that this parameter set in Filter option. I pasted all info in below, not sure if this will work. I'm on SSRS 2014 with most recent updates.  not sure if  expression will help.

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]
[image: screenshot4]

Comment: I  think for me good alternative would be to save data in table, is it possible you think with embedded sql or sp ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple value parameter is not supported by the data extension, as per the error in the page.

However, you can filter the `tablix` with the multiple value parameter.

[image: tablix filter]

Comment: Thanks Abuguid!!  That was I have now (single param works OK), I tried before like on you screenshot, and it's failed, if I set Multiple Param = yes, then it failed even if I select single param. Let me try again.  anybody knows if its possible to store results in table from this dataset ?

Comment: Thanks Abuguid!!  Sorry, disregard my prev comments, Works wonderfully!!!! after I drunk my coffee and read carefully.

Comment: I was confused as backward updates sometime don't work on xml, on a brand new tablix it works OK

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Would be nice to have it properly marked as an answer @MikeS